# Download all files with two different file masks from all folders with WinSCP

Tags: get, winscp

I get missing parameter in GET
It's driving me crazy - tried and read many things with no solution
I want to download all `mp4` and `avi` files in all subdirectories on the server too.

Can't get `-r` switch to work either.

Any ideas? I get "Missing parameter for command 'get'"*.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\Users\HQ\Desktop\winscp.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command "open sftp://%SFTP_USER%:%SFTP_PASSWORD%@%SFTP_HOST% -hostkey=""%HOSTKEY%""" ^
     "cd /home3234/downloads/completed/" ^
     "lcd K:/inbound" ^
     "get   -filemask=.mp4,.mkv"^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download all `.mp4` and `.mkv` files from the folder and all its subfolders, the right syntax is:

```
     "get -filemask=*.mp4;*.mkv *" ^
```

---

*There's no `-r` switch. If you wanted to achieve a recursive download with the switch, note that the `get` command is recursive by default.*

Comment: Thank you. GET can get complicated for a newbie, I appreciate your help with that.